# Angular Material MatInput -> value

Tags: angular-material

I do have this html with Angular Material attributes:

```
<div formArrayName="emails">
    <div *ngFor="let email of emails.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">             
        <mat-input-container>
            <input matInput formControlName=i placeholder="Email- Address">
        </mat-input-container> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The value of **email.value** is not shown in input field and formControlName=i does not work. 
Does anyone know what I have to do in order to show the email- addresses in input fields?

The emails look like this:

```
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({    
    emails: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    ...
 });
```

and is filled like this after getting data from backend oder observable:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.contact.emails.length; i++) {
    this.addEmail();
  }

addEmail() {
    let email = new FormControl('');
    let emails: FormArray = this.form.controls['emails'] as FormArray;
    emails.push(email);
}

let emails: FormArray = this.form.controls['emails'] as FormArray;
for(let i = 0; i < this.contact.emails.length; i++) {      
    emails.controls[i+''].patchValue(this.contact.emails[i]);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
addEmail() {
    const controls = <FormArray>this.form.controls['emails'];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.contact.emails.length; i++) {
        let email = this.formBuilder.group({
          email: [{value: this.contact.emails[i], disabled: false}, [Validators.required]]
        });
        controls.push(email);
    }
}
```